# Trouble Receiving Ethernet Frames with Go

Tags: go, ethernet

I'm working with an older protocol that is Ethernet based (specifically BACnet/Ethernet) so I'm writing an application to send and receive Ethernet frames using Go. I'm using a package from github that so far is pretty good and following the guide located [here](https://mdlayher.com/blog/network-protocol-breakdown-ethernet-and-go/)

I'm working on a Linux platform, specifically a Debian distro. 4.14 Kernal.

I can send frames just fine and verify with Wireshark that they're being sent. I also so the remote devices reply to my frame on Wireshark. However my listen function is not processing the reply in any way. There's no output of any kind or error.

I've followed the example in the linked article but I'll include the source below. This code isn't mine, I dont take credit for it. It belongs to Matt Layher

Why is my application not receiving the reply?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/mdlayher/ethernet"
    "github.com/mdlayher/raw"
    "net"
)

func main {
// Select the eth0 interface to use for Ethernet traffic.
ifi, err := net.InterfaceByName("eth0")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to open interface: %v", err)
}

// Open a raw socket using same EtherType as our frame.
c, err := raw.ListenPacket(ifi, 0xcccc)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
}
defer c.Close()

// Accept frames up to interface's MTU in size.
b := make([]byte, ifi.MTU)
var f ethernet.Frame

// Keep reading frames.
for {
    n, addr, err := c.ReadFrom(b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to receive message: %v", err)
    }

    // Unpack Ethernet frame into Go representation.
    if err := (&f).UnmarshalBinary(b[:n]); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to unmarshal ethernet frame: %v", err)
    }

    // Display source of message and message itself.
    log.Printf("[%s] %s", addr.String(), string(f.Payload))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem.

When you set up the socket to listen on, you have to specify the Ethernet Frame Type. 
In C, this would link back to the frame types in linux/if_ether.h .

If I specify a frame type 0x0003, it works for the BACnet/Ethernet frame and I am able to see the frames come in.